# TypeError: event.bind is not a function

Tags: javascript, discord.js

The error is saying :

```
client.on(event_name, event.bind(null, Discord, client));

                                   ^

TypeError: event.bind is not a function
```

The code (event handler) :

```
const fs = require('fs');

module.exports= (client, Discord) =>{
    const load_dir = (dirs) =>{
        const event_files = fs.readdirSync(`./events/${dirs}`).filter(file => file.endsWith('.js'));

        for (const file of event_files){
            const event = require(`../events/${dirs}/${file}`);
            const event_name = file.split('.')[0];
            client.on(event_name, event.bind(null, Discord, client));
        }
    }

    ['client', 'guild'].forEach(e => load_dir(e));
}
```

Comment: What is `event`? Seems it's not a function or doesn't have a `.bind` method.

Comment: Can you log `event` and tell us the result?

Comment: im new at coding wdym event?

Comment: The variable `const event = require(\`../events/${dirs}/${file}\`);` which you use as `event.bind(null, Discord, client)`

Comment: umm so what do you want me to send?

Comment: Add this line `console.log(event)` right after the declaration of your `event` variable (after this line: `const event = require("../events/${dirs}/${file}");`) And post the output here

Comment: It would be good to know more context, what you want to achieve here?

Comment: to fix the error

Answer (score 0):

An alternative would be to use the spread operator.
This code is assuming you have an execute function similar to the one in the DJS guide.

```js
client.on(event_name, (...args) => event.execute(Discord, client, ...args));
```

[Discord.JS Guide on an Event Handler](https://discordjs.guide/event-handling/)